# How to check SOLR cloud health status or making zookeeper send status

Tags: java, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've a SOLR cloud setup with 8 nodes. I'm using zookeeper with it. I know when a node fails zookper keeps a record of it, and allocates a new master if needed. I want zookeeper to send a notification saying that this node is down. If that is not possible I want somehow to read the current SOLR node health status in zookeeper via java so that I can send out notifications using a custom code. I also don't know how SOLR does that, as I can see the status of all the nodes on SOLR cloud UI. Is there a simple API to pull in this through java. I dont want ot use the SOLR ping API to ping every collection as that is not scalable. So if you guys could help me out with checking the status of all the SOLR cloud , through any of these ways or even suggest a new one, that would be great.

TIA
Sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudSolrServer provides API to retrieve the status of replicas. 
I have an answer posted here if it helps

[Solr API for getting shard's leader/replica status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662619/solr-api-for-getting-shards-leader-replica-status/25673852#25673852)

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for!! Strange StackOverflow didn't suggest this answer while typing in the question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection API for that: [Here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API#CollectionsAPI-api18) and get the cluster state.
If you want to go deeper you can register ur application as Watcher in ZooKeeper and get notified about status change

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. For now I went ahead with techuser's answer as it provided me exactly what I needed, but the watcher application looks pretty good too.I'll try to learn it for future uses.